# How to serve static files from the Snap monad?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I have this Snap site with one top-level location:

```
snapSite :: Snap ()
snapSite = do
    ifTop myHomeHandler
```

In addition to this, how can I serve static files **only if** the request path ends with ".css" or ".txt"?

I noticed there is a `pathWith` function in `Snap.Internal.Core` that could work, but I'm not sure how to fit it into the `Snap` monad above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[Snap.Util.FileServe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-1.0.0.0/docs/Snap-Util-FileServe.html) [c]ontains web handlers to serve files from a directory."

The route will look something like this:

```
("/static", serveDirectory "static_directory_name")
```

For fine-tuning this process you can also use your own `DirectoryConfig` and use `serveDirectoryWith`.